# How to get icinga2 alert data

Tags: monitoring, icinga2

I have set the threshold value to get the alert in icinga2 for infrastructure. Alert is coming on Icinga2 UI but how to fetch this all alert data through API call either using JAVA or python. I need only alert data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [event Stream](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/12-icinga2-api/#event-streams)

Here's an example:

`curl -k -s -u root:icinga -H 'Accept: application/json' -X POST 'https://localhost:5665/v1/events?queue=america&types=CheckResult&filter=event.check_result.exit_status==2'`

This means you'll get data whenever a service goes critical. Here's some more info on [return codes](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/pluginapi.html) incase you need it. Icinga2 uses the same as Nagios.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot.

Comment: in the example you have  given, what 'queue' parameter does

Comment: It just set's a name for that queue. I set it to america but you can use any string.

Comment: Is this the answer you wanted?

Comment: Yes i am getting alert data by using the above API call

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer? There's a check mark under the up down button.

Comment: Thank you, check out [monitoring-portal](https://monitoring-portal.org/). There's alot better people at Icinga there and the devs frequent it.